# A linear transformation and its matrix representation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $ U $ be a vector space and $\beta = \langle u_1, ..., u_n \rangle$ a basis of $U$.
>
> Suppose $T: U \rightarrow U$ is a linear transformation s.t $\eta = \langle T(u_{1}), ..., T(u_{n}) \rangle$ is a basis of $U$ too.
> Is it necessary that $[T] _ {\eta}^{\eta} = [T]^{\beta} _ {\beta}$?

I know the matrices we're asked about are similar, but I'm struggling to develop some intuition about what's going on when it becomes abstract like this. I hope to get some ideas or some tips to develop my intuition at this type of questions.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you work out an example for $n=2$?

Comment: I did that, it seemed to be true at those certain cases however I struggle to see the relation between why it is true to the fact it is actually true in order to make a conclusion

Comment: What is $[T]_{\eta}^{\eta}$ equal to? If you correctly answer this, you’re half way there (or more).

Comment: @peek-a-boo 

$ [T\circ T]^{\beta} _ {\eta} = [T]^{\beta} _ {\eta}[T]^{\beta} _ {\beta} $ 
but now $[T]^{\beta} _ {\eta}$  is obviously $I_n$. Thanks!

Comment: @X4J if you have figured out a solution based on the comments then you should post it as an answer.